# displaying link in php

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I am trying to display a URL stored in mysql as a link in php table like this

```
echo "<td><a href=".$row['resume'].">Resume</a></td>";
```

where $row['resume'] retrieves correct data using mysql_fetch_array

However the whitespace between file link gets truncated automatically

for example my file name is "this is a resume.doc" i only get "this" in link

help.

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($row['resume']);`?

Comment: var dump gives "this is a resume.doc"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place quotes around your href attribute.

```
echo "<td><a href=\"".$row['resume']."\">Resume</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to do several things:

1. Escape characters with special meaning in URLs using [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)
2. Escape characters with special meaning in HTML using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)
3. Quote attribute values

Such:

```
$url = htmlspecialchars( urlencode( $row['resume'] ) );
echo "<td><a href='$url'>Resume</a></td>";
```